# Comparing 2 hashed string to login

Tags: php, pdo, hash

I want to save passwords in my database using:

`$insert_pass = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);`

And when a user needs to login, and if his password is equal to admin and as a hash the admin string is in the database as the following:

`$2y$10$T5Gbe.VJyXihIJGhRJuP9ep3ydh/okw4rlKS/oe9KH3ho83mpmQ1y`

And then when I make a query to see if user have correct credentials:

```
$user = $_POST['user_name'];
$pass = $_POST['user_pass'];//From text boxes
$hash = password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
if($user == "" || $pass == "")
{
    echo $msg = "Please add user name and password";
}
else
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE user_name = :u LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':u', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    if($result)
    {
        //echo $msg = "user exist";
        if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE)
        {
            session_start();
            foreach($result as $row)
            {

                if(password_verify($row['user_pass'], $hash))
                {
                    $_SESSION['userid'] = $row['user_id'];
                    $_SESSION['role'] = $row['user_role'];
                    header("Location: homepage.php");
                }       
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

It is not working and it's not logging in, how to compare a hash password into an existing hashed string ?

I am new to encryption methods and I am building a login system for a company so I need to build a secure method. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In the first parameter of `password_verify` you should pass the unhashed password.

Comment: So my method shown below is secure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not compare a hashed password with the aready hashed password stored on your database. The `password_verify()` does the hashing of the string password using the information the `password_hash()` stored in the hash it made

So your test shoudl be like this

```
password_verify($_POST['user_pass'],$row['user_pass'])
```

Comment: Okay it works now, thank you. But is my method shown above is a secure way sir ?

Comment: Yes, you are not doing anything dangerous with the input password, just comparing 2 fields

Comment: If you fiddle with the `$_POST['user_pass']` in any way you risk making the verify fail when it shoudl have passed